# Set php session as html input value

Tags: php, mysql

I really can't figure out why this isn't working. I want to show the content stored in a php session variable as the value in an input field.

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['id'])
          echo ' <input type="text" value="'.$_SESSION['friday'].'"></input>'; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:
At my login page, index.php, I'm starting the sessions and assigning them values.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("
        SELECT * 
        FROM knine_settings_login, knine_school_db, knine_class_db 
        WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."' AND knine_settings_login.School = knine_school_db.School AND knine_settings_login.ClassID = knine_class_db.ClassID AND knine_class_db.week = 0
        "));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['homework'] = $row['homework']; 
            $_SESSION['pe'] = $row['pe'];
            $_SESSION['pm'] = $row['pm'];
            $_SESSION['pc'] = $row['pc'];
            $_SESSION['School'] = $row['School'];
            $_SESSION['Class'] = $row['Class'];
            $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];
            $_SESSION['schoolurl'] = $row['schoolurl'];
            $_SESSION['monday']=$row['monday'];
            $_SESSION['tuesday'] = $row['tuesday'];
            $_SESSION['wednesday'] = $row['wednesday'];
            $_SESSION['thursday'] = $row['thursday'];
            $_SESSION['friday'] = $row['friday'];
            $_SESSION['peone'] = $row['peone'];
            $_SESSION['petwo'] = $row['petwo'];
```

Comment: Use `isset()` for your session arrays and make sure you've started the session inside all pages using sessions.

Comment: need to see how you have your session...more code please

Answer (score 1):

`Session` Needs to be start before using it.Try It.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.$_SESSION['friday'].'"></input>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the same session more times as plain text and that's working fine. I guess it's already started.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have called `session_start()` before echoing out any `$_SESSION` data.

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['id']) {
    echo ' <input type="text" value="'.$_SESSION['friday'].'"></input>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Start the session on every page at the top first
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["animals"] = "dog";
$_SESSION["cars"] = "ford";
echo ' <input type="text" value="'.$_SESSION['animals'].'"></input>';
?>
```